# Compilation failed in Kotlin due to ? operator

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to understand the following scenario.

```
inline fun Any?.what(ifNotNull: (Any) -> Unit, ifNull: () -> Unit) {
    if (this == null) {
        ifNull()
    } else {
        ifNotNull(this)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
@JvmSynthetic
inline fun <T> T?.whatIfNull(
    whatIfNot: (T) -> Unit,
    whatIf: () -> Unit,
) {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(whatIf, InvocationKind.AT_MOST_ONCE)
        callsInPlace(whatIfNot, InvocationKind.AT_MOST_ONCE)
    }
    if (this != null) {
        whatIfNot(this)
    } else {
        whatIf()
    }
}

fun main() {
    null?.what(
        ifNull = {
            println("It Works!")
        },
        ifNotNull = {
            println("It not working!!")
        },
    )
    null?.whatIfNull(
        whatIf = {
            println("It Works!")
        },
        whatIfNot = {
            println("It not working!!")
        },
    )
}
```

I got something like this for `main` when I compiled this code.

```
   public static final void main() {   }
```

When I remove the `?` operator after `null`, like `null.whatIfNull(` will get

```
public static final void main() {
      Object $this$whatIfNull$iv = null;
      int $i$f$whatIfNull = false;
      int var2 = false;
      String var3 = "It Works!";
      System.out.println(var3);
   }
```

Im trying to understand this too. seems like it only compiled after removing the `?`.

What could be the reason for this issue? Are there any specific blogs or articles? Please post as a comment, or kindly explain me. Thank you.!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The thing is when you write `null?.<anythinghere>` it already knows that `<anythinghere>` is unreachable so it just leaves it out. You might think that `null?` is a value of `Any?` but it is not. So it does not match. Consider this code:

```
fun main() {
    val a = null
    println(a?.test())
    println(a.test())
}

fun Any?.test() : String {
    return "Test"
}
```

Output will be:

```
null
Test
```

When writing `null?` you have an example of the first case, meaning it won't ever execute whatever is after it.

Comment: OK Thanks a lot, I got your point. `null?` is not the value of `Any?`

Comment: @J.K no. The question marks mean different things here. When written behind a value it it is an operator which basically means to not execute the function behind it when the value is `null`. When a question mark is behind a type it means the type is allowed to be `null`.

Comment: Now i got more clarity. @Ivo, thanks for your effort. appreciate you.